# How to call a function dynamically in c

Tags: c, function, dynamic, call, xv6

I am working in the kernel module of XV6.
I need to make a dynamic call like this:

```
proc->tf->eax = hashTable[index]->name();
```

But getting an error:
error: called object is not a function or function pointer

Comment: Did you check the type of `name` before assuming you can just call it? It must be a function pointer in order to be callable. And if you didn't check, how are we supposed to know its type instead of you?

Comment: I guess `hashTable[index]->name` is a c-string, so: why do you think you can call it as a function?....

Comment: `name` is `char*` 
if name = abc, then abc() returns an integer.

Comment: is there another way to call a function dynamically?

Comment: You need to map that string to a function pointer. C offers no reflection mechanism to find a function by name during run time.

Comment: _name is char* if name = abc, then abc() returns an integer_.... using [tag:c]???.....You're a dreamer... ;)

Comment: Instead of `char* name`, what I want is a function pointer.

Comment: But as @StoryTeller told, C provides no reflection. I would create a lookup table from function names to function pointers and use that to figure out what function to call.